# Pandas: Adding a row to each group if missing values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope you're doing okay. I've been trying to think how to solve the next problem, but I can't find a way to do it. Can you guys give me a hand, please?

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, I want to add the remaining rows per group to have 3 Calendar Weeks, I want the new rows to keep the same value of ID of the group and display a NaN value for the Price and Attribute columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input = {'ID':['ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM1', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM4'], 
        'Price':['11', '12', '11', '14', '12', '13', '14', '14' ],
        'Attribute': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D' ],
        'Calendar Week':['1', '2', '2', '1', '3', '1', '3', '2']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(input)

df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Calendar Week'], ascending = True).reset_index().drop(columns = 'index')
```

df =

| ID | Price | Attribute | Calendar Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | 11 | A | 1 |
| ITEM1 | 11 | A | 2 |
| ITEM2 | 12 | B | 2 |
| ITEM2 | 12 | B | 3 |
| ITEM3 | 13 | C | 1 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 1 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 2 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 3 |

Expected output:

| ID | Price | Attribute | Calendar Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | 11 | A | 1 |
| ITEM1 | 11 | A | 2 |
| ITEM1 | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| ITEM2 | NaN | NaN | 1 |
| ITEM2 | 12 | B | 2 |
| ITEM2 | 12 | B | 3 |
| ITEM3 | 13 | C | 1 |
| ITEM3 | NaN | NaN | 2 |
| ITEM3 | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 1 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 2 |
| ITEM4 | 14 | D | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
(df.set_index(["ID", "Calendar Week"])
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["ID"].unique(), ["1", "2", "3"]], 
                                       names=["ID", "Calendar Week"]))
   .reset_index()[df.columns])
```

- you can move ID & Calendar Week to index part
- then reindex with the every possibility of ID versus Calendar Week generated with a product
- then move them back to columns and restore the original column order

to get

```
       ID Price Attribute Calendar Week
0   ITEM1    11         A             1
1   ITEM1    11         A             2
2   ITEM1   NaN       NaN             3
3   ITEM2   NaN       NaN             1
4   ITEM2    12         B             2
5   ITEM2    12         B             3
6   ITEM3    13         C             1
7   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             2
8   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             3
9   ITEM4    14         D             1
10  ITEM4    14         D             2
11  ITEM4    14         D             3
```

Comment: It works! but I have a question, if the Calendar Week is repeated for an ITEM, say: I have two rows of ID: ITEM1, Price: 11, Calendar Week: 1, but with different Attribute 'A' for the first row and "B" for the second row. as we have a repeated index, this solution will not work. Is there a way to tackle this?

Comment: hi @Hapzek sorry for the late response. that seems like a somewhat different question and i don't have a direct solution off the top of my head. perhaps you can ask another question for a larger audience while clarifying the details and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

One option is with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose the missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.complete('ID', 'Calendar Week')
       ID Price Attribute Calendar Week
0   ITEM1    11         A             1
1   ITEM1    11         A             2
2   ITEM1   NaN       NaN             3
3   ITEM2   NaN       NaN             1
4   ITEM2    12         B             2
5   ITEM2    12         B             3
6   ITEM3    13         C             1
7   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             2
8   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             3
9   ITEM4    14         D             1
10  ITEM4    14         D             2
11  ITEM4    14         D             3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `DataFrame` by [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and add original DataFrame by left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), last change order of columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(product(df["ID"].unique(),["1", "2", "3"]),
                    columns=['ID','Calendar Week']).merge(df, how='left')
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df1)
       ID Price Attribute Calendar Week
0   ITEM1    11         A             1
1   ITEM1    11         A             2
2   ITEM1   NaN       NaN             3
3   ITEM2   NaN       NaN             1
4   ITEM2    12         B             2
5   ITEM2    12         B             3
6   ITEM3    13         C             1
7   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             2
8   ITEM3   NaN       NaN             3
9   ITEM4    14         D             1
10  ITEM4    14         D             2
11  ITEM4    14         D             3
```